# AppWidgetHostView is not updating inside AndroidView composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-view

I am building Android launcher using Jetpack Compose, and I need to implement widget hosting, thus I need to pass AppWidgetHostView into Compose. I have successfully done this, but widget is not updating. Here is the code:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
private fun WidgetTest(
    appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager = koinInject(),
    appWidgetHost: AppWidgetHost = koinInject(),
    packageManager: PackageManager = koinInject()
) {
    val widget = appWidgetManager.installedProviders.filterNotNull().onEach {
        Log.d("widgets", it.loadLabel(packageManager))
    }.find { it.loadLabel(packageManager) == "Assistant At a Glance" }!! // I use this as a test widget

    Log.d("widgets", "loading widget ${widget.loadLabel(packageManager)}")
    val appWidgetId = appWidgetHost.allocateAppWidgetId()

    Log.d("widgets", "binding widget ${widget.loadLabel(packageManager)}")
    val canBind = appWidgetManager.bindAppWidgetIdIfAllowed(appWidgetId, widget.provider)

    if (!canBind) {
        val intent = Intent(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_BIND).apply {
            putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
            putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_PROVIDER, widget.provider)
        }
        LocalContext.current.startActivity(intent)
    }

    Log.d("widgets", "building widget ${widget.loadLabel(packageManager)}")

    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            val widgetView = appWidgetHost.createView(context, appWidgetId, widget).apply {
                setAppWidget(appWidgetId, widget)
            }
            Log.d("widgets", "widget built")
            widgetView
        }
    )
}
```

I tried searching, found that I forgot to set the listener up. I've done this in `MainApplication` class:

```kotlin
class MainApplication : Application() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        startKoin {
            androidLogger()
            androidContext(this@MainApplication)
            modules(appModule)
        }

        val appWidgetHost: AppWidgetHost = getKoin().get<AppWidgetHost>()
        appWidgetHost.startListening()
    }
}
```

But widget is still not receiving updates